# Insert a new Google Sheets row into Alphabetically Sorted spreadsheet

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-query-language

I am working with two spreadsheets; the first spreadsheet takes a name and then automatically adds it to the next spreadsheet which is sorted alphabetically by name. The problem is, I need a new row to be created, otherwise the data from the row above it gets added along with the name. Here is the query I am using: '=query(Referrals!A2:O, "select * where C is not null order by D")'. I don't think this can be done with a query, so I have been exploring Google App Scripts. I am not sure how to insert into the pre-sorted list, though. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this with VLOOKUP?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried offsetting the header so you can run it for the range of the sheet?

```
=query(Referrals!A:O, "select * where C is not null order by D Offset 1")
```

That seems to fix some of the issues I've come across.

EDIT:

What about using a filter formula?

```
=sort(FILTER(offset(Referrals!$A:$O,1,0),offset(Referrals!$C:$C,1,0)<>""),4,true)
```

Comment: Awesome!  If you believe that answered your question, go ahead and mark it as an answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is still getting clobbered. The offset simply moves the sheets up a row so I am actually losing some data. When the new row gets created, the data from above gets pushed down into the new row. Is there a way to always generated a new row and honor the order?

Answer (score 0):

If using Apps Script, then you can directly *insert* a row (via [Sheet.insertRows(rowIndex, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsrowindex,-numrows)) into the sheet at the desired  index. But I believe you can achieve what you want by mapping the data in "next spreadsheet" to the names imported via "query" using `VLOOKUP`. That way when new data is added to "first spreadsheet" it will be sorted accordingly with your formula, but now the data associated will move rows to continue matching their respective row.